# Accessing args of a boolean expression using PyEDA

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python, I'm playing with [PyEDA](http://pyeda.readthedocs.org/), and here is my problem: I have boolean expressions like

```
Or(And(a,b),Not(b,c,d), ...)
```

I would like to access the arguments of the boolean functions Or, And, Not. Is it possible? I tried to use module inspect but I get nothing.

Comment: what do your functions look like?

Comment: This kind : And(Or(a, b, c, d), Or(a, ~b, c, ~d), Or(~a, b, ~c, d), Or(~a, ~b, ~c, ~d)) but it may be much more complicated.

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? It's hard to think of a case where you'd have any use for this besides enumerating the ultimate inputs, walking the expression, generating a user-friendly string, or operating on the expression, all of which have simpler and more idiomatic solutions than iterating the arguments.

Comment: The aim is to translate CNF expressions to use in pycosat requests which uses numbers (+5 meaning that variable #5 is True or -2 meaning that variable #2 is False).

Comment: @joel76: Then I think you're approaching this wrong, but without more code it's hard to suggest anything specific.

Comment: @abarnet : Yes, I'm beginner in Python and I'm surely wrong in my approach ! But last night (in France, it was late) I couldn't understand why I could not reach the arguments of an expression, that's all. I understand now that I made a mistake when I wrote my question, I should have written "arguments of a boolean **expression**" instead of "arguments of a boolean **function**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to access the arguments of the boolean fuctions Or, And, Not... Is it possible ? I tried to use module `inspect` but I get nothing.

The `inspect` module isn't necessary here. The result of calling `And(a, b)`—or of writing `a & b` for that matter—is an `And` object, which prints out as `And(a, b)`. And that has an `args` attribute that gives you a list of its arguments:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = map(exprvar, 'abcd')
>>> e = Or(And(a,b), Not(b), c, d)
>>> e
Or(~b, c, d, And(a, b))
>>> e.args
(And(a, b), c, d, ~b)
>>> e.args[0].args
(a, b)
```

Notice that the order may not be the same order you originally gave it. Since `Or`, etc., are commutative and associative, the ordering doesn't matter, so `pyeda` doesn't preserve it. In fact, it's allowed to make more radical transformations than just reordering.

---

If you want to walk the whole expression, you may want to consider using `to_ast` instead of recursively switching on the type and using `args`, however:

```
>>> e.to_ast()
('or',
 ('and', ('var', ('b',), ()), ('var', ('a',), ())),
 ('var', ('c',), ()),
 ('var', ('d',), ()),
 ('not', ('var', ('b',), ())))
```

In fact, just about anything I can think of wanting to do with the `args` can be done better in some other way. If you want to recursively drill down to find the input variables, that's just `e.inputs`. If you want a nice human-readable representation, that's just `str(e)`. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

PyEDA author here.

In a comment you said you want to convert a CNF for use by pycosat. I suggest you just use the `satisfy_one` method, which uses the PicoSAT SAT solver (the same engine used by pycosat).

```
>>> from pyeda.inter import *
>>> a, b, c, d = map(exprvar, 'abcd')
>>> F = OneHot(a, b, c, d)
>>> F.is_cnf()
True
>>> F.satisfy_one()
{c: 0, a: 0, b: 0, d: 1}
# If you want to see the numeric encoding given to the SAT solver:
>>> litmap, nvars, clauses = F.encode_cnf()
>>> clauses
{frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}),
 frozenset({-4, -3}),
 frozenset({-4, -2}),
 frozenset({-4, -1}),
 frozenset({-3, -1}),
 frozenset({-3, -2}),
 frozenset({-2, -1})}
```

Happy programming :).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the use of pyeda is the next step of my project.
I have achieved the first step, solving Sudokus  with pycosat solver (very fast : 0,03s s for a "hard" sudoku !)
I will now try to use pyeda bdd to solve Sudokus. I did it in Prolog with clpb and it is interesting to see how pyeda bdd compares with the SWI-Prolog clpb library.